# What does IP1 mean in neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

I read a slide http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~pstone/Papers/bib2html-links/SDMIA15-Hausknecht.slides.pdf

[image]

What does IP1 mean in neural network?

Comment: @NickCox, I think it is from caffe, if you search google with `IP1 and caffe`, it returns enormous result relating this.

Comment: @NickCox, because the picture is a slide of a paper, and the code is written with caffe. "Deep Recurrent Q-Learning for Partially Observable MDPs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using caffe, IP probably means `InnerProdcutLayer`, which is also know as `FullyConnectedLayer` (FC) elsewhere. IP1 then should be the first `InnerProdcutLayer` of your network.